# SSO with federated sign in in B2C custom policy requires user to choose the social Identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I have a custom policy set up that has local and Azure AD based social authentication.
When used across multiple apps in SSO config, local authentication works perfectly ( i.e. I am not asked to enter credentials and am logged in second app as soon as I hit login)

When using social authentication, when I hit login on the second app, I am redirected to B2C login screen and have to select the social authentication method. Then I am logged in without having to enter credentials.

Can the selection of identity provider be avoided by having the policy read the existing session and react accordingly like it does for local authentication?

```
 <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.localaccountsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AzureAD" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninUsernameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Are you using a Claim from the Social Login that is not being persisted in the relevant SSO Session Provider?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso

Comment: Thanks @Ayush. Azure AD B2C doesn't control the federated identity provider session. Instead, session behavior is determined by the federated identity provider. Please refer this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy